# Return code is: 502, ReasonPhrase: notresolvable

Tags: maven, teradata, nexus

I am trying to upload tera data jars to Nexus repository manually as these are not available in maven central, but i am getting Return code is: 502, ReasonPhrase: notresolvable issue,

Below is the code:
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.teradata.jdbc -DartifactId=tdgssconfig -Dversion=16.00.00.33 -

DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=SFMavenMirror -Durl=http://azurnae-

ap019.xxx.yy.net:2065/repository/maven-central -Dfile=E:/Jars/tdgssconfig-16.00.00.33.jar

Error is :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.teradata.jdbc:terajdbc4:jar:16.00.00.33 from/to SFMavenMirror (http://azurnae-ap019.xxx.yy.net:2065/repository/maven-central): Failed to transfer file: http://azurnae-ap009.xxx.yy.net:2065/repository/maven-central/com/teradata/jdbc/terajdbc4/16.00.00.33/terajdbc4-16.00.00
.33.jar. Return code is: 502, ReasonPhrase: notresolvable. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Comment: I assume the version you are trying to deploy already exists in your repository manager...

Comment: I have verified in nexus repository, there is no tera data jar. i hope it might be some proxy error

Comment: Hi ! kindly let us know if there is any solution, thanks

Comment: Do you have a proxy in between your upload and your NXRM server?  It sounds like something is interfering with the upload.  If you do, you might try disabling it or circumventing it and seeing if that works.  If it does, you'll need to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Hi Joe, we have proxy and tried with proxy and without proxy as well, but same issue again.